# How can I create a reference to a function in a PHP object?

Tags: php

So I am developing a database interface in PHP which outputs objects to represent every Mysql row. In these objects, I want to provide methods to output the data from the rows in different ways, such as combining the `first_name` and `last_name` rows but I don't want every instance of these data objects to reimplement the same method defined in the PHP class.

Does PHP work this way? If so, is there a way to call a method from a PHP object which passes on the input and returns the output from an external function or method?

Comment: Sounds like you're building an ORM... Maybe you want to look at Doctrine or Propel rather than build your own from scratch

Comment: As for your actual question, you could look into **inheritence**, i.e. a parent object could have your shared method and you could extend that class, or **traits** which your class can use

Comment: Can you give a code example of what your trying and where you have problems/doubts about the approach